# I'm having trouble moving items from one array to another through a button

Tags: swift, uikit, uibutton

So I'm new to swift and I'm having trouble making my wishlist button move one item from the array sneakers to the array sneakers1

```
class Sneakers {
    var sneakers = [
        BagProducts(image: UIImage(named: "Image")! , category: "Men" , name: "Adidas Gazelle", price: 100.00, size: "40" , color: "Blue"),
        BagProducts(image: UIImage(named: "Image")! , category: "Men" , name: "Adidas Gazelle", price: 100.00, size: "40" , color: "Blue"),
    ]
    
    var sneakers1 = [
        WishProducts(image: UIImage(named: "AdidasGalaxy")! , category: "Women" , name: "Adidas Galaxy 6", price: 55.00, size: "", color: ""),
        WishProducts(image: UIImage(named: "NewBalance")! , category: "Men" , name: "New Balance BB550", price: 150.00, size: "", color: ""),
    ]
}
```

Here are my arrays

The button is supposed to move only one cell at the time

```
@objc func wishButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) { 
    print("ola- \(viewModel.sneakers1)") 

    for sneaker in viewModel.sneakers { 
        let wishProduct = WishProducts(image: sneaker.image, category: sneaker.category, name: sneaker.name, price: sneaker.price, size: sneaker.size, color: sneaker.color) 
        viewModel.sneakers1.append(wishProduct) 
     } 
   print("ola- \(viewModel.sneakers1)") 
   print("Moved to wishlist") 
}
```

This is the func that I'm using to make it move but when I run it appears this error "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'

```
protocol BagProduct {
   var image: UIImage { get } 
   var category: String { get } 
   var name: String { get } 
   var price: Double { get } 
   var size: String { get } 
   var color: String { get } 
}
protocol WishProduct { 
   var image: UIImage { get } 
   var category: String { get } 
   var name: String { get } 
   var price: Double { get } 
   var size: String { get } 
   var color: String { get } 
}
struct WishProducts: WishProduct { 
   let image: UIImage 
   let category: String 
   let name: String 
   let price: Double 
   let size: String 
   let color: String 

init(image: UIImage, category: String, name: String, price: Double, size: String, color: String) { 
   self.image = image 
   self.category = category 
   self.name = name 
   self.price = price 
   self.size = size 
   self.color = color 
  } 
}

struct BagProducts: BagProduct { 
   let image: UIImage 
   let category: String 
   let name: String 
   let price: Double 
   let size: String 
   let color: String 
init(image: UIImage, category: String, name: String, price: Double, size: String, color: String) { 
   self.image = image 
   self.category = category 
   self.name = name 
   self.price = price 
   self.size = size 
   self.color = color 
  } 
}
```

This are the structs that I used to my product

Comment: What are `BagProducts` and `WishProducts`? You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve], specifically include the definitions for those 2 types. If those 2 types aren't connected through a common protocol or superclass, the array types are different, so you cannot add elements of one array to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can append two arrays of different types (even if they conform to the same protocol) without great effort and custom functions, which I don't know. But there are two easy alternatives to consider: making them the same type, or using map to transform one type into the other.

```
sneakers.append(contentsOf: sneakers1.map { wishProduct in
    BagProducts(
        image: wishProduct.image,
        category: wishProduct.category,
        name: wishProduct.name,
        price: wishProduct.price,
        size: wishProduct.size,
        color: wishProduct.color
    )
})
```